# Get car with limited offers Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

First look my structure code.  I need get limited offers for user car. 
I have hardcode 3 package. Free use got when is registered. Silver and gold. If user subscribe on silver see 8 offers if subscribe on gold see 15 offers. If no subscribe see 2  offers(free package). My code:

User migration:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
```

User model:

```
public function subscriptions_users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subscription');
}
public function cars(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Car');
}
public function offers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

Car migration:

```
 $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('car_type');
        $table->string('mark');
        $table->string('model');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Car model:

```
public function images() {
    return $this->hasMany(CarImages::class);
}
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function offer() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

Offers migration:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('car_id');
```

Offer model:

```
public function car() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Car');
}
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Subscription migration:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('subscription');
        $table->integer('numberOfOffers');
```

Subscription model:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Subscription_user (pivot table with User and Subscription):

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); //foreign key relation
        $table->integer('subscription_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('subscription_id')->references('id')->on('subscriptions')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Subscription_user model:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}

public function subscriptions() {
    return  $this->belongsToMany('App\Subscription');
}
```

Everythink work fine, just i need get offers for car in limited version. Limited version is field  $table->integer('numberOfOffers'); in subscription table.I have maybe problem with relation..I try this but no success:

```
public function getOffers($carID) {
$car = Car::find($carID);
$offers = $car->offer()->limit(THIS IS PROBLEM I DON'T KNOW HOT TO CONNECT USER WITH numberOfOffers)->get();
 return response()->json($offers);
}
```

Comment: Take some time to read https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Your current setup seems to be having conflicts on relationship use and configuration. Your `User` can have multiple `Subscriptions`? If so, you're going to need to query their highest tiered `Subscription` in order to get this working as you want.

Answer (score 3):

when you need to run query on relationship, you should use with method like this:

```php
$offers = Car::where('id', $carId)->with(['offer' => function($query) use ($limit){
    return $query->take($limit);
}])->get();
```

Comment: $limit is undefined variable? 
How to define $limit ?

Comment: I mean the number of offer you need for example 5

Comment: I know that...
How to get that? 
That is question.
@hoseinz3

Comment: change `function($query){` to `function($query) use ($limit){`

Comment: before that query, you should specify the number of offer you want, by another query based on user's subscriptions

Comment: @Davit I changed

Comment: @hoseinz3 I see your changes and your code also must be work(upvote for me)

Comment: The `$limit` is what you showed in your code: `$subscription->numberOfOffers` as you explained right? So he's expecting you to query your limit and use that.

Comment: @Davit Your answer with add relation in Model work, but I always got 3 offers

Comment: @Davit ook your code whick work fine just always return me 3 offers, always. If user silver return 3 offers just that is error

    $car = Car::find($id);
    if(!$car) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Oooops no car found'
        ]);
    }
        $firstSubscription = Auth::user()->subscriptions()->first();
        $limit = $firstSubscription->numberOfOffers;
        $offers = Car::where('id', $id)->with(['offer' => function($query) use ($limit) {
            $query->take($limit);
        }])->get();
    return response()->json($offers);

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public function getOffers($carID) {
    if (!$subscriptionTierLimit = Auth::user()->subscriptions()->numberOfOffers) {
        return Redirect::to('/login'); //You can do whatever redirect here.
    }

    $car = Car::find($carID);
    $offers = $car->offer()->limit(subscriptionTierLimit)->get();

    return response()->json($offers);
}
```

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$numberOfOffers 

@paulELI

Comment: Updated it, try it with `subscriptions()` instead of `subscriptions_users()`

Comment: I am update but again 

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$numberOfOffers"